# Vue js how can i get formatted value from template Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, momentjs

I'm using a 3rd party datetimepicker in my Vue js project. Below are my datepicker parameters

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<datepicker :language="tr" v-model="getRaports.dateSecond"  :format="timeFormat" class="input-md" name="uniquename"></datepicker>
</div>
<button @click="show()">show</button>
          {{getRaports.dateSecond}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6goM.png)

The output of the codes is as follows.
("2018-11-16T22:12:00.000Z")

what I need is just "08-11-2018"

how can i get this format from datetimepicker ? 
Thank you from now.

Comment: What is the name of the 3rd party you are using?

Comment: Hello bro. vuejs-datepicker from charliekassel on github

Comment: Ok, then try my answer. According to their documentation, it should work. https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I assume that string is called like `let mydate="2018-11-16T22:12:00.000Z"` so

```js
let mydate = "2018-11-16T22:12:00.000Z"
let d = new Date(mydate);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, "-")) // output "16-11-2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can point out the 3d party library which you are using, but in any case I think it should work if you pass a standard format into the `format` props like: `dd-MM-YYY`.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<datepicker :language="tr" v-model="getRaports.dateSecond" :format="dd-MM-YYY" class="input-md" name="uniquename"></datepicker>
</div>
<button @click="show()">show</button>
          {{getRaports.dateSecond}}
```